# How to load two urls in webview Together in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

i am loading url in webview.
i have two types of data to display

1)**text(html string)**

2)**url**

here is my code

> To display text

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:[self.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"text"] baseURL:nil];
```

> To display url

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",URL,strpdf];
        NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
        [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

issue is when i loading both data,data is overwrite.
i want to display both data in webview
but right now only text or image is displaying.

what is solution for this.

Comment: @GeneCode as per my requirement in webview top side text and below text i want to display url.

Comment: @Krutarth Patel, do you mean use one `web view` to load two request?

Comment: @aircraft yes exactly

Comment: @Krutarth Patel, or do you mean use one `webView` to load two part info form different url?

Comment: @aircraft right.one webview.one data for text and other url

Comment: @Krutarth Patel, you can do that, give me a url ok? I will give you a demo.

Comment: @aircraft Thanks bro.but i can not share url.can you give demo with google url.?

Comment: @aircraft waiting for your response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132377/discussion-between-aircraft-and-krutarth-patel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My demo is below:

> [image]

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UIWebViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *html_str;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initUI ];
}

- (void)initUI {

    _html_str = @"I love google...";  // the html text you want

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
    _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _webView.delegate = self;

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://chsezhsan195030.e-fae.cn/"];
    NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];


}

#pragma mark - webview delegate

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {


     NSString *script_str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];\
     var script = document.createElement('div');\
     script.innerText = '12345678'%@;\
     script.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';\
     script.style.height = '300px';\
     script.style.backgroundColor = '#eeeeee';\
     body.appendChild(script); \
     body.insertBefore(script, body.childNodes[0]);",_html_str];

    NSString *function = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"var script = document.createElement('script');\
    script.type = 'text/javascript';\
    script.text = \'function myFunction() { \
 %@ };'\
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);", script_str];

    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];

    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction()"];

}

@end
```

But you should attention most of the url is prevented for inject js code,especially the `https` url, so you can not insert the html text above the google's index page.

Comment: Thanks bro for answer.i will check and will let you know

Comment: i have one issue.

Comment: @Krutarth Patel. please post it, if i have time I will help you,

Comment: i want to display at didselectindex of tableview

Comment: @Krutarth Patel, do you mean push a new vc, in the vc display the webView? or other mean?

Comment: No non didselect PopUpView.

Comment: Hi bro.you there?

Comment: @Krutarth Patel. Yes, I am,

Comment: @KrutarthPatel, there is not convenience to communication, send email to me: liaodalin19903@126.com

Comment: @Krutarth Patel. have you send me the e-mail? I did not received it.

Comment: Not yet bro.sorry